# If cell in one column matches cell in another then copy data

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, copy

I've got two separate sheets with a few hundred rows of data.  I'm trying to see if any cell in Column C (Sheet 1) matches with a cell in column A (Sheet 2) then copy over the adjacent cell in column D, E and F to Columns H, I and J (Sheet 2).

I hope it's making sense, I've spent two hours trying to work this out and it's doing my head in.

Sheet 1

```
C1:D1-123    D1:Misc Hinge        E1:Fail           F1: Level 1
C2:D2-635    D2:Seal Split        E2:Pass           F2: Level 2
C3:D2-96a    D3:Scratched frame   E3:Fail           F3: Level 2
C4:D2-1017   D4:Misc Hinge        E4:Fail           F4: Level 2
C5:D2-647    D5:Seal Split        E5:Pass           F5: Level 2
C6:D2-96b    D6:Scratched frame   E6:Fail           F6: Level 2
```

Sheet 2

```
A1:D2-96b    H1:                  I1:               J1:
A2:D2-1017   H2:                  I2:               J2: 
A3:D2-647    H3:                  I3:               J3:
A4:D2-941    H4:                  I4:               J4:
A5:D2-786a   H5:                  I5:               J5:
A6:D1-123    H6:                  I6:               J6:
```

Comment: VLOOKUP should do this, what have you tried?

Comment: Please provide an example of they results you are looking for both either VLOOKUP mentioned above or XLOOKUP should provide you the results you are looking for.